# bootstrap-toggle just shows up as checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap-toggle to create a toggle button according to http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/.

I have the following css and js imports.

all CSS and JS files are latest versions pulled today from the web.

```
  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/agency.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/google_font.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.easing.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jqBootstrapValidation.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/respond.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/html5shiv.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/contact_me.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/classie.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/cbpAnimatedHeader.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/agency.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
```

and my html code is as follows

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <input type="checkbox" name="accounts" id="accounts" data-toggle="toggle">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><input data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox" name="accounts" id="accounts"></li>
            <li>test2</li>
            <li>test3</li>
            <li>test4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code shows up as a simple checkbox.  I would prefer to use modules instead of writing my own code as I am very new as css and js.  Any idea why this is not showing up correctly?

Comment: Have you tried `Initialize by JavaScript` in http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/.